# onsen use navigator into the same page but ons-list append is unusefull

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I am using the onsen on the mobile,I use ,and throw pushPage into one page,for example page1.html,and on the page1.html has a ons-list,I append content to it,it work well,but when I add button on page1.html,and that button is to call the js pushpage to the same page(page1.html),but its not working ,can't  append content ,why?and how to resolve it,please help,thank you very mush.
code flow:
page1.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="zh-cn" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <title>cs</title>
    <style>
        .sp-button {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <ons-page ng-controller="todo">
        <div class="navigation-bar">
            <div class="navigation-bar__left">
                <ons-back-button>back</ons-back-button>
            </div>
            <div class="navigation-bar__center">
                title
            </div>
            <div class="navigation-bar__right">
                    <ons-button id="cs" ng-click="init();" class="button" style="cursor: pointer;width:50px;font-size:small">refesh</ons-button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ons-list id="ToDoDetail">

        </ons-list>
        <div id="kk">

        </div>

        <on-list>
            <div>aabb</div>
        </on-list>
    </ons-page>
</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('app', ['onsen.directives']);
})();


app.controller('todo', function ($scope, $timeout, $http, $location) {


    var listItem = '<ons-list-item>aabb</ons-list-item>';
    $('#ToDoDetail').append(listItem);
    $('#kk').append('ffff');
    $scope.init = function () {
      appNavigation.pushPage('main/sub/page1.html?cs=55', { animation: 'slide'    });
    };
};
```

Comment: don't use `jQuery` in angular controller `controller`, Also you need to compile the DOM using `$compile` before appending it.

Comment: oh,but it can work to append normal,just in the page add a button to use the js function init ,navigation to the self page ,and it is not work ,after append the content ,the page has not changed ,and i don't know how to soluve it.

Comment: that what I said you need add `$compile` in your controller function and then compile div before appending it to DOM like `$('#ToDoDetail').append($compile(listItem)(scope));`

Comment: thank you,i have find the resaon of it,beacause appNavigation.pages have two page1,and $('#ToDoDetail') only find one element,and is the first page1,so i use the method before pushpage :var pages = appNavigation.pages;  for(var i=0;i<pages.length;i++) {if(pages[i].name.indexOf('page1.html')>=0) pages[i].destroy;}  appNavigation.pushPage('main/sub/page1.html');

Comment: @PankajParkar - can you help me in my onsen ui question?

Comment: @Mindlife - can you help me in my onsen ui question?